# Setting 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz networks with same settings

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

If I give my 5 GHz network and 2.4 GHz the exact same name (SSID) and password, will my devices connect to both, so far my Surface 2 Pro only seems to connect to the 2.4 GHz?

I’m using a [Nighthawk r7000](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/R7000.aspx) with [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) if that is any help.

Answer (score 3):

If the same SSID is available in both 2.4 and 5GHz frequencies, then Windows is supposed to "decide" which one has better signal and use it.  In reality it never does.

The trouble is that the antenna can only determine signal strength from the device to the base station, but not the other way around.  Also it can't see how much channel crowding there is on the 2.4GHz band, which can get quite bad in a crowded neighborhood.

My standard practice is to give the 5GHz band a different SSID so I can decide which one to connect to manually instead of letting the computer decide.

Answer (score 2):

You have to force 5 GHz in the registry (if your unsure, please be careful with the below as it can have seriously bad conscequences if you change anything incorrectly).

I found these instructions on a website a while ago cannot remember which one but I used it on mine and saved it to my OneDrive:

1. Open Regedit
2. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Class
3. Right click class and select FIND
4. Search for this: 2.4
5. When you find it, you should be in some random Hexadecimal folder. (Mine was called {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
6. Under that one, you should see a number of folders labelled 0000, 0001, 0002, and so on. Check 0000 for a string called DriverDesc with a value of EXACTLY this: "Marvell AVASTAR 350N Wireless Network Controller". If you don't find it under 0000, move onto 0001. Mine was under 0003, but yours may vary
   6*** It is possible that you will happen upon "Marvell AVASTAR Wireless Composite Device". This is NOT the one you want.
7. Find the value called "Band". By default, it has a value of 6.
8. Change the Band value to your preferences (Mine is set on 1, which is enforce 5ghz)
9. Reboot. You should now have your 802.11 preference set!

Reference: Here's what the different values of the Band variable do:

7: Untested.

6: Default mode. 802.11a/b/g/n. 2.4GHz and 5GHz

5: 802.11b only. 2.4GHz only

4: 802.11b/g only. 2.4GHz only

3: 802.11b/g/n only. 2.4GHz only

2: 802.11a only. 5GHz only

1: 802.11a/n only. 5GHz only

0: disabled. No Wi-Fi

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Robotnik, in my defense it was 7:30am :) ha

Comment: Just to clarify if i get out of range of the `5 GHz` network will it on its own reconnect to the `2.4 GHz` network? and is this specific for the Surface or will it work on any PC?

Comment: @Peter - Even though they might have the same SSIDs you would have to connect to each of them manually, tell Windows to connect to it and remember the password, in order to do what you describe because they are still not identical.  Of course the distance for both *2.4 Ghz* and *5.0 Ghz* 802.11n are identical.

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm, when i list my networks i can only see one i don't see 2 networks with the same name...

Comment: @Peter - This answer just explains how to force your network adapter to always pick the 5.0 Ghz SSID.  As I indicated the signal distance will be the same for both given all conditions are equal.  It does not explain how to get two SSID that are identical to automatically connect.  I wouldn't call them the same honestly for that reason.

Comment: @Ramhound can you explain why i can't see both networks in windows, if they indeed are two different networks why can't i see both?

Comment: @Peter I cannot because your end goal isn't even possible.

Comment: @Ramhound i don't get your logic, if they are indeed 2 separate networks then the should show up as two different networks they don't only one network shows up...

Comment: @Peter - What you want is not possible.  This answer provides an answer to an entirely different question.  It took me awhile to realize that myself.  As I said before you are not going to extend the range of your network by doing this.